# How to use display:grid to create a responsive two columns layout where both columns must have a minimum and/or maximum width?

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

When a container has enough space I want the children layout to be two columns, but, if there is not enough space, they should just be two rows taking the entire width. (typical responsive grid)

I can do this the usual way with media queries. But I'd like to know if there is a better solution using `display:grid`. Especially that media queries only work with the viewport width and would want this to work at container level. (avoiding JS solutions like resizeObserver)

I wish it behaved like this:

- If there is enough space (min-width: 30em):
  A: Column width:10em + B: column minimum 20em
- If there is not enough space (< 30em):
  A (= row full width)
  B (= row full width)

Can this be done with `display:grid` and without media queries? This should also work with space between children like grid-row-gap.

Comment: `minmax` can make this work.

Comment: @zzzzBov Could you add how you would do it? I haven't managed to do it.

Comment: Re-reading this now I was wrong earlier. Didn't realize the columns were different widths. [You can use flexbox for most of what you want](https://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/dqBdpJ), but you won't be able to use `gap` just yet.